# Reset a property count once an array is filtered

Tags: javascript

I have the following array

```
let array = [{a: "hi", index: 0}
    ,{a: "hi1", index: 1}
    ,{a: "hi2", index: 2}
    ,{a: "hi3", index: 3}
    ,{a: "hi4", index: 4}
    ,{a: "hi5", index: 5}
    ,{a: "hi6", index: 6}]
```

I do

```
array.filter((i, index) => index > 3)
```

This returns

```
     [{a: "hi4", index: 4}
    ,{a: "hi5", index: 5}
    ,{a: "hi6", index: 6}]
```

But i need it to return

```
  [{a: "hi4", index: 0}
  ,{a: "hi5", index: 1}
  ,{a: "hi6", index: 2}]
```

How to do that?

Comment: If the index is equal to the index they are in the array, why have an index property at all?

Comment: I agree . This seems pointless and open to needless potential bugs. What is the index property used for that you can't use the array index instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get there using `array.map` on the end of `array.filter` to reset the index - but resetting the index is problematic

```js
let array = [{a: "hi", index: 0}
    ,{a: "hi1", index: 1}
    ,{a: "hi2", index: 2}
    ,{a: "hi3", index: 3}
    ,{a: "hi4", index: 4}
    ,{a: "hi5", index: 5}
    ,{a: "hi6", index: 6}]

let b = array.filter((i, index) => index > 3).map((e,i) => ({...e, index: i}))
console.log(b)
```